# Installing SIPp on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sip

I am using this tutorial to install SIPp on Ubuntu 16.04 x64 . It worked on my local machine (vmware) but I get an error on the remote server. I am using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFm4EfYtYC4 .

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal  --output=aclocal.m4t
Can't exec "aclocal": No such file or directory at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 326.
autoreconf: failed to run aclocal: No such file or directory
```

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure that `autoconf` is installed on your remote server.  `sudo apt-get install autoconf`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/so2wr7 the same problem appears.

Comment: Sorry about that, make sure that `automake` is installed on the remote.  `sudo apt-get install automake`

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please give me some reputation.

Comment: I wrote it up as an answer for you.  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that error because `automake` is not installed on the remote host.  To resolve it, run the following on the remote host:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install automake
```

Hope this helps!